# Find all existing connections in multiple Excel files in a directory

Tags: excel, powershell

Due to server changes, I have been asked to find the Workbook Connections used for all spreadhseet reports (200+) stored within a folder directory. Is there a way of using powershell to find these?

I had tried using the following powershell command but I think I am maybe going about it incorrectly.

```
Get-ChildItem “C:\path” -recurse | Select-String -pattern “find me” | group path | select name
```

Any help would be very appreciated! Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
foreach ($file in (Get-ChildItem “C:\path_to_reports\” -recurse))
{
$Excel = New-Object -comobject Excel.Application
$ExcelWorkbook = $Excel.workbooks.open($file.fullname) 
write-host "Connections of $($file.fullname):"
$ExcelWorkbook.Connections
$Excel.Close()
}
```

Comment: Martin you are a lifesaver. That worked perfectly thank you :)