# Find Excel connections paths using PowerShell/R/VBA

Tags: r, excel, vba, powershell

I need to list all the connection paths from multiple Excel files. So far, I have been able to get the connections names, but I require the full path. I have used the following PowerShell code, posted by a fellow user [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34923003/find-all-existing-connections-in-multiple-excel-files-in-a-directory).

```
ForEach ($file in(Get-ChildItem "\path\to\file" -recurse))
{
$Excel = New-Object -comobject Excel.Application
$ExcelWorkbook = $Excel.workbooks.open($file.fullname)
write-host "Connections of $($file.fullname):"
$ExcelWorkbook.Connections
$ExcelWorkbook.Close()
}
```

I also have R and VBA in hand to make this happen, but I could not think of any way to do this in any of them.

Thank you!

Comment: By connection do you mean linked file?

Comment: Yes, a linked text/csv file, for example

Comment: In VBA, you can parse the [`TextConnection.Connection`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.textconnection.connection).